# How to fix a fan's corrupt configuration?

Tags: power-management, fan, sensors

My fan have noise issue.After doing `pwmconfig`, i found **from 120 till 255**(these are called pwm speed i guess) ,most are corrupts.Is there any way to fix it?Any application?Good with both linux and windows application.Sorry if couldnt explain properly and thanks in advance.

**edit-1**

```
PWM 255 FAN 1962
PWM 240 FAN 1467
PWM 225 FAN 2385 (probably incorrect)
PWM 210 FAN 3245 (probably incorrect)
PWM 195 FAN 3013 (probably incorrect)
PWM 180 FAN 2755 (probably incorrect)
PWM 165 FAN 2436 (probably incorrect)
PWM 150 FAN 2136 (probably incorrect)
PWM 135 FAN 1790 (probably incorrect)
PWM 120 FAN 1486
PWM 105 FAN 1397
PWM 90 FAN 1344
PWM 75 FAN 1290
PWM 60 FAN 1247
PWM 45 FAN 1201
PWM 30 FAN 1171
PWM 28 FAN 1165
PWM 26 FAN 1161
PWM 24 FAN 1157
PWM 22 FAN 1153
PWM 20 FAN 1149
PWM 18 FAN 1146
PWM 16 FAN 1144
PWM 14 FAN 1140
PWM 12 FAN 1134
PWM 10 FAN 1134
PWM 8 FAN 1130
PWM 6 FAN 1128
PWM 4 FAN 1123
PWM 2 FAN 1121
PWM 0 FAN 1117
```

Comment: Is it just really noisy?  What do you mean by corrupt?

Comment: Its you again! Yes its most probably corrupt.! 1sec let me add more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that when power is applied to the fan near 100% or the time, it's not operating at full speed.  I would recommend replacing the fan as it is not performing optimally.

To get around this issue without replacing the fan, you can set the maximum pwm value to 210 and it should solve the issue.

Edit `/etc/fancontrol` and look for MAXPWM.  If the file does not exist, please complete `pwmconfig` and save it so pwm3 is in the file.  If MAXPWM is not in the file, add it.  Use the same notation that is already there for MINSTART and MINSTOP, so if you have a MINSTART that looks like this:

```
MINSTART=/sys/devices/platform/it87.656/hwmon/hwmon1/pwm3=70
```

Then your MAXPWM would look like:

```
MAXPWM=/sys/devices/platform/it87.656/hwmon/hwmon1/pwm3=210
```

Though I find it interesting that [someone else](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1249390/i-downloaded-fancontrol-to-bring-my-computers-temperature-down-but-what-do-t/1249638#1249638) just had this same issue and it had to be set to 210 as well.  It's possible that it's not the fan but the motherboard itself that is causing the issue.

Comment: To add  more info on the subject and your interest, i think its most probably has something  to do with windows10! .  i started having this(fan noise) problem about year a ago, the day when installed win10 and for this very reason i don't have a  good view on win10.